# Xamarin.Android C# GetItemId() not defined?

Tags: c#, android-layout, xamarin.android

For the following code i am getting an error. How do i solve it? I just started android development and dont know anything much.

```
public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
    {
        Type thing = item.GetType();
        String id = item.getItemId();}
```

Error CS1061: Type `Android.Views.IMenuItem' does not contain a definition for`getItemId' and no extension method `getItemId' of type`Android.Views.IMenuItem' could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference? (CS1061) (V002)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Xamarin Android you have to use `item.ItemId` instead of `item.getItemId()`

If you need to cast it to string then:

```
if(item.ItemId.ToString() == "certainId")
{
   //so something here..
}
```

Comment: But when i use item.ItemId, it produce an integer. How to i compare it with a string Id? say i want to do: IF (item.ItemId == "certainId"){ Do following} END IF, How would i achieve it?